# Resources for mathematician trying to develop (macro)economic thinking?

Tags: macroeconomics, books

I have a 'hobbyist' interest in economics (read several popular science econ books and listen to a lot of podcasts).

Recently I've been trying to take this further by looking at courses in economics. I have a strong maths background (PhD in stats), and I find a lot of early undergraduate courses interesting, but they often seem to ignore the underlying maths, so feel like they are missing out some important detail. On the other hand, I find graduate level courses a good level but feel like they don't build my economics 'intuition'; which I get the impression is very important to develop economic thinking.

My question is are there any resources that offer a good balance between the two? I'm particularly interested in macro, but any micro resources would also be interesting.

Comment: Could you state what specific resources you've looked at but did not find satisfactory? That way people answering will have a better idea of what you're looking for.

Comment: For the more advanced stuff I tried some of the macro lecture notes from this [list](http://econphd.econwiki.com/notes.htm). For the less advanced I tried the khan academy and recommended undergrad textbook, as well as these [MIT OCW lecture notes](https://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/91563/14-02-fall-2009/contents/lecture-notes/index.htm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be interested in David Romer's Advanced Macroeconomics. It's a grad-level textbook that includes grad-level math, but the focus is off the math and on the intuition. It doesn't spend much time going over certain tools, like dynamic programming, so it gets a bit hand-wave-y at some points, but it sounds like this might be the right balance for you.

Comment: Thanks that sounds like a great balance